# Spring.NET, Quartz & Transactions

Tags: spring.net, quartz.net

I've just run into a problem with a Quartz job that I'm invoking through Spring. My `ExecuteInternal` method had a `[Transaction]` attribute (because it does a load of DB calls) but when it runs, I get the 'No NHibernate session bound to thread' error.

Just wondering if that's because Spring.NET doesn't support the `[Transaction]` attribute in Quartz objects?

If not, that's fine... I can start a transaction manually, but wanted to check that it was the case, and not a silly error in my config somewhere.

**[Update]**
I figured it out actually. In the API docs, it says the preferable way to do this is use transactions on the service layer. My job was using DAOs to do its work, but my transactions are on my service layer, so I just called service methods from my job instead to do the same work (saving, updating records etc) since they already existed.

It also suggests that if you give the SchedulerFactoryObject a DbProvider, you can use transactions in the job itself, but when I did that it seemed to want to find my triggers configured in a special table in the DB (which I haven't set up since my triggers are all in XML) but that's possibly another way to do it.

Calling service methods works fine for me though.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept you own answer. This way everybody knows you problem is solved.

Comment: Will do. I have to wait 8 hours apparently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction attribute works using aop. Spring.NET creates an aop *proxy* for the decorated object. This proxy creates the session and starts the transaction.

In the `ExecuteInternal` method, you don't call the method on a proxy, but on the target itself. Therefore spring cannot intercept the call and do its transaction magic.

Your services *are* injected and therefore the transaction attribute works for them.

There's a good explanation in the spring docs on this subject: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html#tx-understandingimpl